# Data "derivation" in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

It seems like a really basic concept, but I'm not even sure what to search for here. The few tries I've done all failed spectacularly.

Basically I have the following:

```
parameter(id PK, type_id, data...)
parameter_string(id PK, string data...)
parameter_float(id PK, float data...)
// etc, lots of them
```

`parameter.id` uniquely identifies the parameter itself, and `parameter.type_id` uniquely identifies one of the various tables containing data specific to that type. All the "derived" tables' `id` fields are unique across all of them, so simply selecting an `id` uniquely identifies the type right away.

Another requirement is that the same parameter subclass can be "part of" different parameters, and this is achieved because the `parameter.type_id` field can point to the same parameter "subclass" `id`.

So the way I'd like to represent that is to have each parameter's `id` field be a foreign key linked to `parameter.type_id`, but I get an error complaining that "The columns in the table 'parameter' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE contraint". And yes, that's obviously true. However I don't understand why that's a requirement, and how I can work around it and still keep something similar to my structure.

Answer (score 0):

I need to guess a bit about what your question is, because you are not very specific about what exactly it is you want to ask ;-)

For me it seems that you can build your data model like this. To query all of your data at once you'd have to join all subclasses such as

```
select parameter.id, parameter.data, parameter_string.data, parameter_float.data, ...
from parameter left outer join parameter_string on parameter.type_id = parameter_string.id
    left outer join parameter_float on parameter.type_id = parameter_float.id
-- ...
```

Or if you only need the string parameter values, just do an inner join instead.

Regarding your second issue/question: it is the other way around: `parameter_string.id` is the primary key of the `parameter_string` table.
`parameter.type_id` is the foreign key, but because it references several tables at once, you cannot have this as a foreign key constraint in that sense...

To learn more, you could do a search for something like **relational database model generalization**.

Comment: I know how to query it, I just don't know how to build it while still maintaining foreign keys. The other way obviously doesn't work because I can only link a foreign key to one table, it has to be from the "subclasses" upwards, except that it still doesn't let me.

Comment: But that conflicts with your second paragraph saying _"Another requirement is that the same parameter subclass can be "part of" different parameters, and this is achieved because the parameter.type_id field can point to the same parameter "subclass" id."_ - This is a _n:1_ relationship. Or even n:1 several times for several subclasses. And with the tables you have, you only can have the reference on the _n_-side. Anything else would mean to introduce an additional reference table "in between" to hold the foreign keys into both parameter and parameter_xxx ...